# Lost ability to write to NTFS USB disk using MacFUSE and OS X

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs, macfuse

Up until recently I was able to read and write files from my MacBook Pro to my 1.5TB USB Western Digital HD.  I recently lost that ability after a friend copied a folder onto the harddrive from his Macbook Pro.

Now I can only read from the HD, I cannot write to it.

I've tried this on other of my Macs and even with MacFUSE installed I cannot write files to the drive.

I can write files to the drive using a Windows machine, however, I noticed that the friend had created an empty folder, which I get an error trying to remove, even from the Windows machine!  What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but probably there's something corrupted on the filesystem and that's why the driver refuses to do any writes... to make sure there's not more going to brake.

If I were you I'd run Checkdisk from the Windows machine and see if it comes up with anything...

worst case fix: get all the data off the disk and just reformat it.

Comment: @sketchfemme:  You may not even have to do a chkdsk:  It might be enough to mount the disk and unmount it on Windows since the act of mounting will roll forward or back unresolved volume journal actions.  Properly dismounting it will clear (or set?) the bit which says the volume is okay.